# A View object per page? or just one View object loading different templates?

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller, view

In my application I have one `View` object which can `load($template)` a template to get it ready to be rendered using the `render()` method.

In all the stuff I have read about `Views` sometimes I see people doing it the way I currently do it and other times I see people doing something like the following

```
class ProductView extends View {

}

class CheckoutView extends View {

}
```

Having a separate `View` per page.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of both ways?

Any advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>View should not be "loading templates". If you have code like `$this->load('header');` in the view, then it is a violation of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). View (sometimes) **uses** templates to create a response for the user, but it should not be creating them.</sub>

In the most of the articles that you will encounter about view, you will read about the interpretation of view from Rails (ands its clones). In RoR you do not have view. Only a glorified dumb template.

The structure of presentation layer makes it preferable for you to have 1:1 relation between controllers and view. Each view becomes responsible for handing of the response that has been triggered by user's input. Therefore: you page would usually have a *one view per execution time*.

In more complex cases you might want to look into concept of [composite view](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/CompositeView.htm). This approach lets you separate the the presentation logic in smaller chunks. This also makes it much easier to structure your code, if you user [ViewModel](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

The bottom line is this: if you have one view per whole application, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to start using multiple Views from now on. I am going to start using `ViewHelpers` so in my new `Product` View for example should it have a property like `private $productHelper` if that view needs a `ViewHelper`?

Comment: Honestly, I fail to see the reason for even having view helpers. I would use ViewModel instance to contain any logic that has no place in the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

The one view-per-page is definitely most suitable for the web. Watch out that I didn't mean one view-per-controller but per different page. You want to have different templates that can be called by different views (such as the header, the footer or the navigation bar).

For example inside `BlogPostView` you would have:

```
$this->load('header');
$this->load('post', $data);
$this->load('footer');
```

and then render it with:

```
$this->render();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the biggest advantage of having a separate `View` do you think? I have recently come across `ViewHelpers` and if I have a separate `View` per page it would be easier to assign specific `Helpers` to each `View` I would think, is that correct?

Comment: @David, it really depends on your vision of the MVC pattern. Patterns are not standards, you can follow them, adapt them or don't follow them. It just comes down to what you think is best for you in your current application design. The MVC pattern just tells you how to divide data, logic and presentation and what relation should run trough these elements. Hot you actually design the models, views or controllers is just your call.

Answer (score 0):

It has no "the only true solution". 
But as for me, View must be as simple as possible. Like printf function. Do you want to extend printf behaviour? I think no!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would you go about supplying `ViewHelpers` with only `View` object? Have a `ViewHelperFactory` in the `View` maybe?

Comment: It depends on starting point. I need neither helpers nor helperfactory. Because of my wish list (for View class) is quite short. Do not ask presentation to do a lot.

Comment: P.S. In real world it is important to assign responsibilities. View is for front-enders, at most. That is why templates are more natural way, IMO. Front-end guy can be 0 in PHP.